# .NET project, hundreds of version conflicts and no idea where they are from

Tags: .net, nuget

We have a .NET solution made of 5 projects; 3 of them are 'standard libs' we use everywhere and are product specific.

When I compile with detailed logs, I see hundreds of conflict errors.

So I simplified things to the first two project and I still get a lot of lines like this:

> Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Reference:System.IO'.  Choosing 'Reference:System.IO' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.1.0'.

Lib 1 doesn't directly refer System.IO; Lib 2 refers it and has version 4.1.2.0

So, I guess that Lib 1 indirectly depends on System.IO.
After looking at references, it turns out that System.IO.Filesystem depends on System.IO, but from an older version.

The real question is if these errors can cause problems? there is a massive amount and since we're constantly in nuget versioning hell with the shared libs, and always have to remove the references in app.config to get anything to compile, I am curious if this is something I should look more into or not.

I am assuming the app.config is there to remap one version to another, but with shared code it really fails horribly.

Comment: Maybe you are using different .NET Frameworks in the projects.

Comment: no, everything is very rigid and it is all .NET 4.7; The problem seems to arise when the packages get updated: they'll be updated in the context of one project, the changes to the main lib will get pushed to the repo and other projects will get these; then the app.config from the project that was updated and from the other projects pulling the changes start to not match anymore.

Comment: 'Reference:System.IO' that smells like some .net core right there. I agree with @UweKeim. Challenge your assumption. Go look at everything with a microscope.

Comment: yes, it has that; I should have clarified: the 3 main core libs are made of 2 .NET 4.7 libs + 1 lib which is a .NET Core but still using the .NET 4.7 runtime. It's created from VS as a .NET Core lib but we select .NET 4.7 as the framework.

Comment: I answered it a few days ago. Microsoft is aware of this and you can simply ignore them now.